# Asp.net Core 2.1 HttpClientFactory: second api call is not waiting for first api call's returned result

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, httpclientfactory

I encountered an issue using HttpClientFactory. I need to call two web methods from one third party web api.

1. getOrderNumber.
2. getShippingLabelFile.

Call #2 depends on #1's result since it needs to pass orderNumber to it e.g.:

```cs
await _client.getAsync("http://xxx/api/getLabel?orderNumber=[returnedOrderNumber]&fileType=1")
```

When I set break-point and debug, it works as expected. Without debugging mode, #2 web method always failed. I have done investigation. If I pass static query parameter like:

```
http://xxx/api/getLabel?orderNumber=123&fileType=1
```

it works fine. It seems #2 evaluates the query string and execute api call before orderNumber gives to it. It is very frustrating, can you please shed on some light on this issue?

On Controller:

```cs
private readonly ISite1AuthHttpClient _site1HttpClient;

public OrderShippingOrdersController(site1AuthHttpClient)
{
    _site1HttpClient=site1AuthHttpClient
}

[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetShippingLabel(int id)
{
    string token=await _site1HttpClient.GetToken(username.ToString(),password);
    string orderNumber=await _site1HttpClient.CreateOrder(Order,token);

    if (orderNumber!=null && orderNumber!="")
    {
        //this API call always failed during runtime. It works on debugging mode.
        var streamFile=(MemoryStream)(await _site1HttpClient.getShippingLabel(orderNumber,token));

    }
}
```

HttpClient Type Class:

```cs
public interface ISite1HttpClient
{
    Task<string> CreateOrder(AueCreateOrder order,string token);
    Task<Stream> GetShippingLabel(string orderNumber,string token);
}

public class Site1HttpClient:ISite1HttpClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public Site1HttpClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://abcapi.Site1.com/");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));

        _client = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<string> CreateOrder(AbcCreateOrder order,string token)
    {
        var jsonInString=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order);
        jsonInString="[ " + jsonInString + " ]";

        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",token);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsync(
            "api/AgentShipmentOrder/Create", new StringContent(jsonInString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            AbcOrderCreateResponse abcRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AbcOrderCreateResponse>(contents);
            return abcRes.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            var errorResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            throw new Exception(errorResponse);
        }
    }

    public async Task<Stream> GetShippingLabel(string orderNumber,string token)
    {
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",token);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync("api/GetOrderLabel?orderId="+orderNumber+"&fileType=1");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Stream streamFile= await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            return streamFile;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("failed to get label.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all I'd add logging. It's so much easier if you see what happens compared to guessing… https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Most likely your order number is not what you expect to be and I would use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() witch will cover null, empty and white space

Comment: For your code, `orderNumber` has the return value. I assume even through the third party return `orderNumber`, it has not save back to database yet in the third party. I would suggest you try query the order by orderNumber before `_site1HttpClient.getShippingLabel` to check whether the order exists. To check this issue, try Thread.Sleep before `_site1HttpClient.getShippingLabel` to narrow down this issue. You also need to confirm the third party support.

Answer (score 0):

```
string token = _site1HttpClient.GetToken(username.ToString(),password);
string orderNumber = await _site1HttpClient.CreateOrder(Order,token);
```

I guess the problem occurs because of first await keyword. When you use await for the first function call (calling an async function), you declare that your program does not need to hold on for the response. So the token variable is used in the second function when it is not set. As you can see above, you should be good to go without the first await for the token variable.